# Recode continuous variable_summary

Tags: r, categorical-data, summary, continuous, recode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siPzV.png)

After recode from continuous variables into categorical. The summary for the new categorical variable doens't show how it summarize for categorical in levels we often see.

Please help!

Comment: Converting your variable `resize`to a factor will show you the levels when calling `summary()`.

Comment: Please don't add data/code as image. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
A4 <- within(A4, resize <- factor(Size > 1000, c("S", "L")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` does precisely this.

```
A4$resize <- cut(A4$Size, breaks = c(-Inf, 1000, Inf), labels = c("S", "L"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `findInterval`

```
A4$resize <- with(A4, c('S', 'L')[findInterval(Size, 1000)])
```

---

Or using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
A4 %>%
   mutate(resize = case_when(Size > 1000 ~ "S", TRUE ~ "L"))
```